# WP8: Native application silently exits and restarts when resuming - reproducible with the VS2012 D3D sample project

Tags: windows-phone-8

My native D3D game silently exits and restarts when resuming. I only see these errors when resuming the game:

```
The thread 0xb44 has exited with code -2147467260 (0x80004004).    
The thread 0x300 has exited with code -2147467260 (0x80004004).    
The thread 0x9b0 has exited with code -2147467260 (0x80004004).    
The thread 0x914 has exited with code -2147467260 (0x80004004).
```

And then the game seems to start normally but it's back to the beginning screen.

Note that this doesn't happen if the game was paused by pressing the lock button. Only happens if the game was paused using the home button.

Also, this is not an issue in my game because you REPRODUCE IT EASILY using the sample Native D3D project that ships with VS2012. Anybody had this issue before?

I just submitted my game and I'd be really pissed if it is rejected because of this. This happens in the D3D sample too.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the same error code in a different situation. In a managed c# app, in the middle using the app on low end devices like the Lumia 520, the whole phone will randomly restart, and the debugger will show -2147467260.